# SQL columns grouped by one value output in a row

Tags: sql, group-by

i never heard about that but one of my friends needs help with an SQL code.

He wants to bring up a table where all records grouped by one value are in one row.
In fact you don't know how many records there can be I don't know if it is even possible.

For example you have this table:

`Name | Role | Place
A    | 1    | Place1
B    | 2    | Place1
C    | 3    | Place1
D    | 1    | Place2
E    | 2    | Place2
F    | 3    | Place2
G    | 1    | Place3`

Now my output should be like:

`Place  | Role 1| Role 2| Role 3|
Place1 | A     | B     | C     |
Place2 | D     | E     | F     |
Place3 | G     |       |       |`

Is there any possibility to do that?

Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Here's a tutorial how to transpose your table. http://oracletuts.net/sql/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql/

Comment: ah okay, that's quite good. But my problem is that i don't know how many columns i need. in this case i have so add as many as i need but when i use one more it wont display.